# Binomial Response Difference Between Samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, proportion

I have a data set of 500 companies which have been clustered into groups based on their answers to survey questions. I'm trying to gauge whether the profitability between groups is statistically different, and if so what the correct test is to use.

Profitability is indicated as a binary variable (1,0).

1. Sample

   - n = 500
   - profitable = 203
2. Cluster 1

   - n = 198
   - profitable = 78
3. Cluster 2

   - n = 159
   - profitable = 55
4. Cluster 3

   - n = 143
   - profitable = 70

So far I have used the binomial propotions test to determine whether the sample mean statistically different than the cluster mean. Is this the correct route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 500 values in 'sample' and the 500 values in the three clusters are the *same* 500 values, then your use of a binomial proportions test is flawed (it assumes independence, but you're reusing observations in both samples). The test statistic won't have the tabulated distribution.

If that's what happened then you can either test one cluster against the other two combined (in each of the three possible combinations), or you can test each pair of clusters (again, three possible combinations). I'd suggest the latter. Either way the tests won't all be independent.

Or you can test two contrasts (which can potentially be made orthogonal), for example, if you were interested, say in cluster 1 vs cluster 2, and then cluster 3 vs the rest.

You could instead do one overall test of equality (test the null that all the proportions are equal against the alternative of at least one inequality), and then if you wish do the equivalent of pairwise multiple comparisons.